# Database not getting refreshed when using 2 apps at the same time

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm posting a video of the problem for clarity because I'm not sure that I will be able to explain it in words: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCDG91zbgoI
Basically, I have 2 identical apps connected to the same database. I want to run them both at the same time.

When I try to get the information from the DB only from one app - no problem. But when I run both, I change the information with the command "Change" in one of the apps. Then use "Show" in the other - the information I get is outdated(the one before I used "change" on the first app). The database gets updated, but the second app doesn't get the latest information from the DB. Restarting the 2nd app and then using "Show" returns the newest information, but that won't help me. The `Player player = context.Players.First(p => p.ID == 1);` inside the  `while(true)` should mean that the information taken is always the newest, but I guess not.
Here is the whole code:

```
TTTContext context = new TTTContext();
while(true)
{
        string command = Console.ReadLine();
    Player player = context.Players.First(p => p.ID == 1);
    if (command == "Show")
    {
            Console.WriteLine(player.Name);
        }
    else if (command == "Change")
    {
         string name = Console.ReadLine();
         player.Name = name;
         context.Players.Update(player);
         context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here is my TTTContext class:

```
public class TTTContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("Server=localhost;Database=Test;Uid=root;Pwd=Martin1234;");

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Often this kind of concurrency trouble happens because the updating process did not COMMIT its changes. It's hard to help you further without seeing your `TTTContext` class's code. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones - he has commit, because value is updated in DB. I would suspect "repeatable read" or caching in the context.

Comment: Is this EF? If so, set the entity state to modified so the cache is aware it has changed.

Comment: What happens if `context.Players.First(p => p.ID == 1)` is replaced with `context.Players.AsNoTracking().First(p => p.ID == 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `context.Players.First(p => p.ID == 1)` with `context.Players.AsNoTracking().First(p => p.ID == 1)` fixes the issue.

Comment: Answering your own question is okay on Stack Overflow, but when you get the idea from a comment, then it is considered good form to give the person who wrote the comment the chance to turn it into an answer, so that they receive the credit.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm new here, I thought this is what I'm supposed to do - to not leave the question open, when I have the answer, since he wrote it as a comment. I will keep it in mind for further questions.